# how to handle error which returns from async task and program should continue

Tags: c#, task

I have below code which throws error on a certain condition when `i % 2 == 0` or `i % 2 != 0`. I want to handle the error and I want to execute the program continuously, how to do this?

```
  class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            i++;
            var task1 = WriteDouble(i);
            var task2 = WriteString(i);

            await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

            await Task.Delay(10000);
        }

    }

    private static async Task WriteString(int i)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error");
        }

        await using var file = new StreamWriter($"C:\\Temp\\test1-{i}.txt");
        await file.WriteLineAsync($"this is string-{i}");
    }

    private static async Task WriteDouble(int i)
    {
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error");
        }
        await using var file = new StreamWriter($"C:\\Temp\\test2-{i}.txt");
        await file.WriteLineAsync($"this is double-{i}");
    }
}
```

Comment: put a try-catch around your while loop in main

Comment: @auburg you mean "put a try-catch around *the code inside* your while loop in main"?

Comment: @PeterBons Yes - you're right. I missed  the requirement for it to continuously loop (so how would the program terminate?).

Answer (score 1):

If you put `try-catch` inside loop, your loop will be able to continue looping even if exception is thrown:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        try 
        {
            i++;
            var task1 = WriteDouble(i);
            var task2 = WriteString(i);
            await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
            await Task.Delay(10000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

We can find the tasks causing exceptions using `Where` linq method:

```
var throwers = tasks.Where(task => task.Exception != null);
```

An example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        int i = 0;
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                i++;
                var task1 = WriteDouble(i);
                var task2 = WriteString(i);
                tasks.Add(task1);
                tasks.Add(task2);
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                await Task.Delay(10000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var throwers = tasks.Where(task => task.Exception != null);
                var test = ex.Message;                        
            }
        }                
    }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();            
}
```

And other methods:

```
private static async Task WriteString(int i)
{            
    throw new Exception("Error");
    await Task.Delay(1000); // 1 second delay
}

private static async Task WriteDouble(int i)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000); // 1 second delay
}
```

Comment: Task delay then should be outside of catch block. but any other way? I think something on Task level

Comment: how to print which task is fail?

Comment: @user584018: Put a separate try/catch around each method that may throw an exception. Or don't throw from `WriteString` and `WriteDouble` but handle and log the error in these methods.